# Why is ListView not refreshing?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview

Hi I am inserting into a table then reading everything back into a `ListView` When I re-open the program I see the data I just saved in my `ListView`, but this record is not showing in my `ListView` at the time of saving (although it is saved in the table).

I am using

```
 listView.Update()
```

as well as

```
 listView.Refresh()
```

but it does not seem to work. I am just using a `SELECT` query to read data off the `datareader` and store it in my `listView` as follows (which is working properly)

The only problem is that the listView is not refreshing immediately, but it works when I close/open the program

here's the code I am using at the end of my Save method. basically these two methods get called

```
  Private Sub SetColumns()
    Dim lstpenalty As New ListView()
    lstpenalty.Items.Clear()
    lstpenalty.Visible = True
    lstpenalty.Bounds = New Rectangle(New Point(390, 55), New Size(560, 379))
    lstpenalty.Name = "lstpenalty"
    lstpenalty.FullRowSelect = True


    lstpenalty.View = View.Details
    lstpenalty.GridLines = True


    lstpenalty.Items.Clear()


    lstpenalty.Columns.Add("a", 75)
    lstpenalty.Columns.Add("b", 70)
    lstpenalty.Columns.Add("c", 105)
    lstpenalty.Columns.Add("d", 98)
    lstpenalty.Columns.Add("e", 90)
    lstpenalty.Columns.Add("f", 105)
    Me.Controls.Add(lstpenalty)



    LoadPenaltyList(lstpenalty)

End Sub

Private Sub LoadPenaltyList(ByRef listView As ListView)

    Dim gDR As OracleDataReader
    Dim cmd As New OracleCommand
    Dim lstpenaltyview As New ListViewItem

    Try

        cnn.Connect_to_Oper_Agent()
        cmd.Connection = cnn.cnn

        listView.Items.Clear()


        cmd.CommandText = " select a," & _
                          "b, " & _
                          "c, " & _
                          "d," & _
                          "e," & _
                          "f" & _
                          " FROM myTable" & _
                          " commit"

        gDR = cmd.ExecuteReader()


        While gDR.Read

            lstpenaltyview = listView.Items.Add(Null_To_String(gDR("a")))
            lstpenaltyview.SubItems.Add(gDR("b"))
            lstpenaltyview.SubItems.Add(gDR("c"))
            lstpenaltyview.SubItems.Add(gDR("d"))
            lstpenaltyview.SubItems.Add(gDR("e"))
            lstpenaltyview.SubItems.Add(gDR("f"))

        End While

        listView.Update()



    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("There was an error... -> " & ex.ToString)

    Finally
        cmd.Dispose()
        cnn.Close_Conn()

    End Try


End Sub
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Those two methods just redraw the control with its current data. You need to populate it again with new data.

Comment: Right after the user clicks save (which does the insert) I am calling two methods. One of them is re-building the listView and the other one is reading the new data off the tables

Comment: Showing code might help..

Comment: Post the method you use to populate the ListView originally and the code you are using after pressing save.

Comment: @user1683987 You are using Windows Forms, right?

Comment: @Zefnus Just updated it with the code

Comment: @CathalMF Just updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was creating the ListView dynamically. The issue was that it kept creating ListViews over each other (memory leak), and it always showed the previous one. I created a static viewList versus a dynamic one and the issue is resolved:D

Answer (score 0):

It is worth looking at what methods do.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview_methods%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Update :    Causes the control to redraw the invalidated regions within its client area.

Refresh:        Forces the control to invalidate its client area and immediately redraw itself and any child controls.

To update it using table info, first Clear the listview, then redo the process you used to initially populate it.

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
For Each i As Windows.Forms.ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
   i.Remove()
Next
```

Instead of `Clear`

Comment: You should format this so that it looks like code.  And add some explanation about how this solves the problem.